# HTML.Encode() - What/How does it prevent scripting security problems in ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net, security

What security protection does HTML.Encode() afford me when I'm dealing with user input, specifically scripting problems?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Please see [`Server.HTMLEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347.aspx):

> The HTMLEncode method applies HTML
>   encoding to a specified string. This
>   is useful as a quick method of
>   encoding form data and other client
>   request data before using it in your
>   Web application. Encoding data
>   converts potentially unsafe characters
>   to their HTML-encoded equivalent.
>
> If the string to be encoded is not
>   DBCS, HTMLEncode converts characters
>   as follows:
>
> - The less-than character (<) is converted to `&lt;`.
> - The greater-than character (>) is converted to `&gt;`.
> - The ampersand character (&) is converted to `&amp;`.
> - The double-quote character (") is converted to `&quot;`.
> - Any ASCII code character whose code is greater-than or equal to 0x80
>     is converted to `&#<number>`, where
>      is the ASCII character value.

This means that if you are going to dump some data to the request stream and that data was saved to the database from a user-entered field it will prevent users from being able to say that their first name is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomethingEvil() { /* ... */ }
</script>
```

In this example, `Server.HTMLEncode` would encode the `<`, `>`, and `"` characters leaving this:

```
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
    function doSomethingEvil() { /* ... */ }
&lt;/script&gt;
```

which, if rendered in the browser will look like this:

> <script type="text/javascript">
>      function doSomethingEvil() { /* ... */ }
>   </script>

rather than actually executing.

Comment: Not sure you would get a chance to read this but if you do, could you clarify how all of a sudden browser will decode the html encoded string? I asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/q/72981511/2719527 to clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 5):

it prevents XSS (cross site scripting) attacks, since if it **prevents** users input to turn into scripts that can be used to perform this type of attack