# Images not showing in tinMCE

Tags: tinymce

I had set up tiny MCE and it was saving text to the database with an image tag. When I went to edit the content, I would see the image correctly in the editor. All of a sudden, when I go to edit, I see the actual image tag and not the content.

[image: <img title="2018-12-17_14-19-37.png" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAkwAAADXCAYAAADoWg5qAAAACXB]

Answer (score 0):

I bet this happens after that content is retrieved from the backend/database, doesn't? It's because your content is [htmlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014611/189673) on some stage. You need to find that place and rethink the logic around it, so that html tags reach the editor intact.